# GWT getUrl does not return image

Tags: gwt

I have an image in my war folder. I am trying to see what the image is, but I cannot get it to work. I am trying by using `GWT.getModuleBaseURL()`but it does not alert.

```
if(soundImage.getUrl().equals(GWT.getModuleBaseURL()+"/soundOn.png")){
                    Window.alert("YEP IT DOES");
                    soundImage.setUrl("soundOff.png");
                    setSound("off");
                }else{
                    soundImage.setUrl("soundOn.png");
                    setSound("on");
                }
```

How can I get the image? Am i overlooking something in my code, or am I doing it wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the URL of an image in order to change the view is understandable if you have an HTML background, but is sort of crazy in GWT-land. This is roughly analogous to changing the URL of a `<script>` on the fly -- it's technically possible, but strange. This image is a child of some component, necessarily. I would replace this image by operating on the component that contains this image, and not on the image itself by changing its URL. The URL of an image is essentially its descriptor, so it's awkward to change a property like this. If you are using MVP and have created a `View`, then you might expose a method like `void toggleSoundImage(boolean on)`.

You really should be doing this instead: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideUiImageBundles. The way you are trying to use images is unidiomatic  -- some people might call this "wrong".

I purposefully did not answer your question because if you were doing this correctly, the preconditions that caused this problem wouldn't exist.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Notice you you are setting the url (`soundOn.jpg`) using a relative path, but you are checking using the module absolute path.

The URL should merely be the same as the `src` attribute on your image.

If you use:

`if(soundImage.getUrl().equals("soundOn.png")){`

It should work. I recommend using Travis' recommendation of Image resources, also.